# Adjust display items with grid and flexbox

Tags: html, css

I'm new to CSS and I created a simple container with logo and text content. I achieve this:[image]

I use display grid and flex depending on what I'm doing, the first thing is there is a lot of space between the logo and text container, I want them closest to each other and align text container at `right: 0`

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u2vdqytk/)

SCSS:

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  // text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  justify-items: center;
  float: right;
  margin-left: auto !important;
  margin-right: initial;

  &__overlay {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background-color: #48525D;
    border-radius: 129.5px 0px 0px 129.5px;
    padding: 4% 4%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    right:0;

    &-item {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: left;
    }
  }
}

.logo {
  width: 100%;
}

.title {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-family: "Exo 2", sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-size: 4rem;
  text-align: left;
}

.subtitle {
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 1.4;
  font-family: "Exo 2", sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-size: 5rem;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.label {
  font-family: "Exo 2", sans-serif;
  color: #A60A2D;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 3.8rem;
  font-weight: bold;

}
```

HTML:

```
   <div class="container">
     <div class="container__overlay-item">
       <img class="logo" src="https://logo.clearbit.com/facebook.com">
     </div>
     <div class="container__overlay">
       <div>
         <p class="title">Title Test</p>
         <p class="subtitle">This is a title test</p>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is just to use flex alone and adjust logo size and font sizes based on screen size. This will solve your issue and increase responsiveness in your layout

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin-top: 5em;
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:row;
  justify-items: flex-end;
  margin-right: initial;

  &__overlay {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    background-color: #48525D;
    border-radius: 129.5px 0px 0px 129.5px;
    padding: 4% 4%;
    max-width: 1200px;

    &-item {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: left;
    }
  }
}

.logo {
  max-height: 100px;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}


.title {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-family: "Exo 2", sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-size: 4rem;
  text-align: left;
}

.subtitle {
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 1.4;
  font-family: "Exo 2", sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-size: 5rem;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.label {
  font-family: "Exo 2", sans-serif;
  color: #A60A2D;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 3.8rem;
  font-weight: bold;

}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px){
  .logo {
     max-height: 80px;
   }
   .title {
     font-size: 3rem;
   }
   .subtitle {
     font-size: 4rem;
   }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
  .logo {
     max-height: 60px;
   }
   .title {
     font-size: 2rem;
   }
   .subtitle {
     font-size: 3rem;
   }
}
```